# upstart script is not picking system default environment variable

Tags: upstart, openstack, services, locale, environment

I have one openstack based service. Which we are ran using `upstart` script.

**upstart script**

```
# filename: /etc/init/myservice.conf

start on runlevel [2345] and started mountall
stop on runlevel [016]


env OS_SVC_ENABLE_CONTROL=1
export OS_SVC_ENABLE_CONTROL

pre-start script
  mkdir -p /var/run/myservice
  chown -R myservice:myservice /var/run/myservice
end script

respawn
# the default post-start of 1 second sleep delays respawning enough to
# not hit the default of 10 times in 5 seconds. Make it 2 times in 5s.
respawn limit 2 5

exec start-stop-daemon --start -c myservice --exec /opt/stack/bin/myservice --

post-start exec sleep 1
```

When I check my system `locale`, its showing `LANG=zh_CN.UTF-8`.

```
root@localhost:~# locale | grep LANG
LANG=zh_CN.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
```

When I run the upstart service, `LANG` is showing as empty string (means not set for upstart service)

If I gave `env LANG=zh_CN.UTF-8` in upstart script, its working fine.

Why upstart is not taking default `locale`?

Why we have to set same `env` in our upstart script?

Answer (score 1):

Upstart by default will launch jobs in a very restrictive environment.  My guess why it does this, for at least one reason, is that it can't assume you want to run the job as root, or any other given user. So it tries to be restrictive and secure by default.

See: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#job-environment

Comment: Is there any way to set `LANG` for user by which upstart run service?